# How can I extract a substring?

Tags: delphi

I have function in delphi

```
function GetHardDiskSerial(const DriveLetter: Char): string;
var
  NotUsed:     DWORD;
  VolumeFlags: DWORD;
  VolumeInfo:  array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  VolumeSerialNumber: DWORD;
begin
  GetVolumeInformation(PChar(DriveLetter + ':\'),
    nil, SizeOf(VolumeInfo), @VolumeSerialNumber, NotUsed,
    VolumeFlags, nil, 0);
  Result := Format('%8.8X',
    [VolumeSerialNumber])
end;
```

---

how to take the output
character to 2 up to 4.

Example: 7121334

- Result must be: 121

cSerial.text=......................................

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `Copy` function to extract a sequence of characters from a string:

```
cSerial.Text := Copy(Result, 2, 3);
```

Note that the third parameter is the number of characters to extract, not the index of the last character.

Comment: Depending on how you're using the extracted characters later I'd consider checking the length of the string and setting a boolean if it's not long enough. For example, If Length(Something) >= 5 then HaveSerial:=True; When needed you can test with If HaveSerial then ... Just a thought because you'll get an empty string if it's not long enough.